# No such file or directory - git config init.defaultbranch (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby

I installed Ruby on rails on cmd, but it had error as No such file or directory - git config init.defaultbranch (Errno::ENOENT). I can't solve this problem.

I tried installing on the web guide but it wasn't fixed
[image]

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Is git installed?

Comment: I didn't install git

Comment: Ok, I suggest running `git --version`. If this does not return a version, it's not installed at all. To learn how to install it, follow the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this error by Installing git on my local machine and the error was gone, please find attach link to git installer https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: There are alredy similar answers posted and you don't add anything to them. Please refrain from posting such answers in the future or [edit] you post to add useful information

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, install `git`.

Run `git --version` to check if git is installed. If not, follow [these steps to install git](https://github.com/git-guides/install-git) - there are installers for Windows and Mac.

#### Why does this error occur?

Rails tries to run `git init from "."` to initialize a repository in your current working directory.

Rails [reads](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a98e28a31d3b9a720c4a9571c23b40433a035df/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L484)  the git default branch, see [this post on superuser.com about the default branch](https://superuser.com/questions/1419613/change-git-init-default-branch-name).

To configure the init.defaultBranch parameter in git > 2.28, you can run `git config --global init.defaultBranch main`.

Not sure why you would do it but you could skip this step by using these console options:
`-G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]`
`-p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]`

See [Rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2b2e789cb714dab2d37db8c7449d1f229ea8257f/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin/plugin_generator.rb#L69) and run `rails new --help` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can run, rails new ProjectName, it on Vs Code instead of the Command Prompt.

This gives you a quick fix

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this error by going into the directory where Git was installed and running the git console

```
git-cmd.exe
```

and inside this console, the command

```
rails new C:\dir.... path to new project\new project name
```

Understanding that it is a PATH problem, I need to know what directory I have to add to the PATH, where Git is installed or more specifically the Bin directory within that same directory, etc.