# Project on ruby on rails created incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, project

When creating a project on ruby, I do not create folders, but only files.

```
E:\Gamess\Ruby>rails new blog
  create
  create  README.md
  create  Rakefile
  create  .ruby-version
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  .gitattributes
  create  Gemfile
     run  git init from "."

C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:258:in ``': No such file or directory - git config init.defaultbranch (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:258:in `user_default_branch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:76:in `version_control'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:134:in `public_send'        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:134:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:328:in `create_root_files'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/rails:25:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/rails:25:in `<main>'
```

I tried to create a project in other folders[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEPzu.jpg)

Comment: is git installed on that machine?

Comment: Install git -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71627367/no-such-file-or-directory-git-config-init-defaultbranch-errnoenoent

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error before. Please install Git and then try creating a new Rails application.